# My driver's license was suspended for not having insurance. Should I even bother to apply for a medical?

Tags: faa-regulations, medical

My insurance lapsed for a few days, and during that few days that I got caught.

Furthermore, it's the second suspension in my life because I got a bunch of tickets when I was younger.

I hold a sport-pilot license which would be invalidated if I was rejected for the medical.

Comment: Why would you be applying for a medical? Are you going for a full license?

Comment: I can't understand your question. How does a driver license relate to your medical?

Comment: Before voting to close be aware that license suspensions can lead to the loss of an existing medical or denial of a new one, IMO this is a valid question although it could be phrased a bit better.

Comment: If your drivers license is suspended, I'm pretty sure your sport pilot license is also invalid because you are required to have a current, **valid** driver's license to exercise your privileges. It would be the same if a PPL's medical were revoked.

Comment: It would help if you would [edit] your question and add some details - what exactly are you trying to do?  Determine if it's legal to fly sport pilot while your drivers license is expired?  Determine if you can upgrade to a private pilot's license with a revocation on your record?  Something else?

Comment: How many days is "a few days"? Do I even want you at the controls of something that could fall on my house?

Comment: For the certain answer, ask an AME (ask for a consultation, not an exam), but I've never heard of routine traffic tickets in the past being cause to deny a 3rd-class medical.  DUI and assorted drug/alcohol issues, certainly, but normal traffic tickets, no. Fix the suspension before flying (or going to the AME for that matter), but with everything in good shape this doesn't sound like a reason to be denied a medical.  IANAL, IANAAME, etc etc.

Comment: The suspension is already "fixed" in the sense that I've paid the reinstatement fee and all that, but the suspension is still on my record and I'll have to report it.

Comment: @GdD Yes, I may be going for a full license.

Comment: @A.I.Breveleri "A few days" was 10 days, and my income has gone up by 5x since then. I'll never have the kind of money problems that led to that situation again.

Comment: In that case I withdraw my objections. Good luck with the AME.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A sport pilot license does indeed require a valid driver's license **OR** a minimum third-class medical certificate. If you don't have a medical certificate, you cannot exercise sport pilot privileges until your driver's license is reinstated.

Comment: My driver's license was reinstated. The problem is that now there's a suspension on my record and I'll have to tick "yes" on the corresponding question if I apply for a medical.

Comment: You don't need a medical to continue exercising sport pilot privileges. You just need a valid driver's license.

Comment: I want to upgrade to a PPL. I will need a medical before doing so unless they remove that requirement.

Comment: You have two options:

1. Don't tell the FAA about the suspension. (Bad idea, IMO. They will find out, and that's worse than not telling.)

2. Make an appointment at the FSDO to talk to them about the issue and explain the situation and events that led to that, *before* you visit the medical examiner.  You'd be surprised how well communication (respectful, thoughtful) works with FAA employees. They have to follow the rules, but they will help you find the way to get that medical if they can.

3. Talk to the medical examiner first and ask what he thinks you should do.

Comment: For those of you paying attention, that was three options. LOL!

Answer (score 2):

The objective, as outlined in the NPRM, for medical review of driver licenses is to determine if there are behavioral issues which may impact the judgment of a pilot.  Drugs, alcohol,  and other risk behaviors are screened and evaluated.  There are cases where excessive speeding tickets and reckless driving has contributed to the non-issuance or revocation of a medical certificate.

To be clear, common traffic violations, are normally of no concern.

The FSDO is not involved in the medical process, but is involved in the enforcement process, so officially, they can be of little help.  The Aeromedical Certification Branch of the FAA is the responsible branch.  Substance dependence, substance abuse and personality disorders which involve overt acts are disqualifying.

Comment: In my experience, anything you disclose to aeromedical can and will be used against you. I learned the hard way that you don't tell them what they don't need to know.